# Двойное нажатие ЛКМ

Tags: c++

Я хочу сделать программу, которая при одном клике делает второй(нужно для копирования от 1 клика). Но,что я не пробовал, всё-равно выполняется не так. У меня есть код

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
    isClicked = false;
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
    int x = p.x;
int y = p.y;
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0);
Sleep(250);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
isClicked = true;
Sleep(250);
```

GetAsyncKeyState не работает корректно из-за чего клик повторяется вновь и вновь после 1 нажатия.

Comment: Второй клик тоже одиночный клик по сути;) Поставь флаг или счетчик кликов. После каждого четного не вызывай обработчик

Comment: В разных библиотеках используются разные подходы для решения этой проблемы: в одних не генерируется в принципе эвента двойного нажатия (вместо этого генерится два одиночных), в других генерится два одиночных и один эвент двойного нажатия, в третьих выставляется значение задержки, исходя из которого отбрасываются два одиночных и вместо них создаётся один эвент двойного нажатия. В вашем же вопросе даже название библиотеки не указано.